# VoiceInteractionService API21 startSession error

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, voice-recognition

i'm tring to write a hotWord application with the latest API21 and with VoiceInteractionService, AlwaysOnHotwordDetector and VoiceInteractionSession.

i've created an activity that call to

**startService**(new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainInteractionService.class));

MainInteractionService:

```
public class MainInteractionService extends VoiceInteractionService

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    ctx = getApplicationContext();
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate!!!!!!!!!! ");
    onReady();
 }

@Override
public void onReady() {
    super.onReady();
    Log.d(TAG, "onReady!!!!!!!!!! " );
    Locale bLocale = new Locale("en", "US");
    //hotwordDetector = createAlwaysOnHotwordDetector("Hello", bLocale, callback);


 @Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onStartCommand!!!!!!!!!! ");
    //hotwordDetector.startRecognition(hotwordDetector.RECOGNITION_FLAG_ALLOW_MULTIPLE_TRIGGERS);
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    Log.d(TAG, "args: "+args);
    startSession(args);
    stopSelf(startId);

    return START_NOT_STICKY;
}
```

** when onStartCommand is being called the app crush and the following log cat error appears:

Caller is not the current voice interaction service

Does anyone know what to do?
i've search anywhere but there is so little info and example about this API

logcat:

```
Process: com.test5.simpleapphotword.simpleapphotword, PID: 29450
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service com.test5.simpleapphotword.simpleapphotword.MainInteractionService@17c3e453 with Intent { cmp=com.test5.simpleapphotword.simpleapphotword/.MainInteractionService }: java.lang.SecurityException: Caller is not the current voice interaction service
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2881)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2100(ActivityThread.java:144)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1376)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
 Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Caller is not the current voice interaction service
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1540)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1493)
        at com.android.internal.app.IVoiceInteractionManagerService$Stub$Proxy.startSession(IVoiceInteractionManagerService.java:248)
        at android.service.voice.VoiceInteractionService.startSession(VoiceInteractionService.java:143)
        at com.test5.simpleapphotword.simpleapphotword.MainInteractionService.onStartCommand(MainInteractionService.java:78)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2864)    
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2100(ActivityThread.java:144)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1376)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Answer (score 0):

You app must be put as default assist app in order to use a `VoiceinteractionService`. I don't in Lollipop, starting from Marhsmallow you find the menu in Settings -> App -> Advanced -> Assist.